# Flushing a boost::iostreams::zlib_compressor. How to obtain a "sync flush"?

Tags: c++, boost, zlib, flush, boost-iostreams

Is there some magic required to obtain a ["zlib sync flush"](http://www.bolet.org/~pornin/deflate-flush.html) when using [`boost::iostreams::zlib_compressor`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/zlib.html) ?  Just invoking `flush` on the filter, or `strict_sync` on a `filtering_ostream` containing it doesn't see to do the job (ie I want the compressor to flush enough that the decompressor can recover all the bytes consumed by the compressor so far, without closing the stream).

Looking at the [header](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/boost/iostreams/filter/zlib.hpp), there seem to be some "flush codes" defined (notably a `sync_flush`) but it's unclear to me how they should be used (bearing in mind my compressor is just added into a `filtering_ostream`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out there is a fundamental problem that the `symmetric_filter` that
`zlib_compressor` inherits from isn't itself flushable (which seems rather
an oversight).

Possibly adding such support to `symmetric_filter` would be as simple as adding the `flushable_tag` and exposing the existing private flush methods, but for now I can live with it.

Comment: Here's a PR to add it: https://github.com/boostorg/iostreams/pull/116 - nobody seems to review it though.

Answer (score 1):

This C++ zlib wrapper library, of which I'm the author, supports flush functionality and is arguably simpler to use:

https://github.com/rudi-cilibrasi/zlibcomplete

It is as easy as this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <zlc/zlibcomplete.hpp>

using namespace zlibcomplete;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  const int CHUNK = 16384;
  char inbuf[CHUNK];
  int readBytes;
  ZLibCompressor compressor(9, auto_flush);
  for (;;) {
    cin.read(inbuf, CHUNK);
    readBytes = cin.gcount();
    if (readBytes == 0) {
      break;
    }
    string input(inbuf, readBytes);
    cout << compressor.compress(input);
  }
  cout << compressor.finish();
  return 0;
}
```

The main difference from boost is that instead of using a template class filter you simply pass in a string and write out the compressed string that results as many times as you want.  Each string will be flushed (in auto_flush mode) so it can be used in interactive network protocols.  At the end just call finish to get the last bit of compressed data and a termination block.  While the boost example is shorter, it requires using two other template classes that are not as well-known as std::string, namely filtering_streambuf and the less-standard boost::iostreams:copy.  The boost interface to zlib is incomplete in that it does not support Z_SYNC_FLUSH.  This means it is not appropriate for online streaming applications such as in TCP interactive protocols.  I love boost and use it as my main C++ support library in all of my C++ projects but in this particular case it was not usable in my application due to the missing flush functionality.

Comment: Perhaps you can demonstrate a concrete sample here on StackOverflow on _how_ this in your opinion, as author of the library, is simpeler to use?

Comment: Thanks I did that, appreciate the feedback.