# Why boost::iostream::filtering_ostream using boost::iostreams::zlib_compressor needs to be destroyed for the sink to be written?

Tags: c++, boost, iostream

After spending quite some time debugging the issue today, I noticed the `boost::iostream::filtering_ostream` needs to be destroyed for the sink to be written.

Test code:

```cpp
#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_stream.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filter/zlib.hpp>

#include <sstream>

struct ZlibOstream : boost::iostreams::filtering_ostream
{
    ZlibOstream(std::ostream& os)
    {
        boost::iostreams::filtering_ostream::push(boost::iostreams::zlib_compressor{});
        boost::iostreams::filtering_ostream::push(os);
    }
};

int main()
{   
    std::ostringstream oss;
    
    #ifdef HAS_SCOPE
    {
    #endif
    
    ZlibOstream zlibOstream{oss};
    
    zlibOstream << "This is a test string.\n";
    
    #ifdef HAS_SCOPE
    }
    #endif
    
    return (oss.tellp() == 0);
}
```

Calling `flush()` doesn't do the trick and I don't need to do this when I remove the `zlib_compressor`.

Result with coliru: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7cd166d2d820e838

What would be the reason behind this behavior ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in fact related to this question:

[Flushing a boost::iostreams::zlib_compressor. How to obtain a "sync flush"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468792)

You need a call to `boost::iostreams::zlib_compressor::close` for the flush to happen.

You can achieve this by calling either `pop()` or `reset()` on the `boost::iostream::filtering_ostream`.

Note, `pop()` as its name suggest pop the last filter in the chain and `reset()` clear the chain completely such that the `filtering_ostream` won't be usable afterward.

Example:

```cpp
#include <boost/iostreams/filtering_stream.hpp>
#include <boost/iostreams/filter/zlib.hpp>

#include <sstream>

struct ZlibOstream : boost::iostreams::filtering_ostream
{
    ZlibOstream(std::ostream& os)
    {
        boost::iostreams::filtering_ostream::push(boost::iostreams::zlib_compressor{});
        boost::iostreams::filtering_ostream::push(os);
    }
};

int main()
{   
    std::ostringstream oss;

    ZlibOstream zlibOstream{oss};

    zlibOstream << "This is a test string.\n";

    zlibOstream.reset(); // needed if you want to write to oss

    return oss.tellp();
}
```

Comment: there is `boost::iostreams::close` free function